# How do I fix my Discord app command? It keeps saying "The application did not respond" and "Dispatching MESSAGE_SEND_FAILED"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a decent amount of experience with JavaScript, so I hoped that **creating a Discord app** would be relatively approachable. It seems to be, and **I was able to add the bot to a server and deploy a command** which Discord lists in the commands list.

The bot I hoped to create would only **allow users to pin or unpin a message using the message's URL**. I don't want to give people the "Manage Messages" permission because I don't want them to delete messages.

The command they use would end up looking like this:

```
/pin https://discord.com/channels/1234567891234567891/1234567891234567891/1234567891234567891
```

The app would then check to see if the message belonged to the channel or thread the command was used in, and it would pin the message if it isn't pinned and unpin it if it is.

I have condensed the code to the index.js file so it's all in one place; this is the code that I have (assisted by the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin)):

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.commands = new Collection();
client.commands.set('pin', {
 data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('pin')
  .setDescription('Pins or unpins a message in a text channel')
  .addStringOption(option =>
   option.setName('message')
    .setDescription('The link to the message to pin or unpin')
    .setRequired(true)),
 async execute(interaction) {
  try {
   await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
   const message = await interaction.channel.messages.fetch(interaction.options.get('message').value);
   if (!message || message.channel.id !== interaction.channel.id) {
    await interaction.followUp('Invalid message link');
   } else {
    if (message.isPinned) {
     await message.unpin({ reason: `Unpinned by ${interaction.user.tag}` });
     await interaction.followUp(`Unpinned message: ${messageLink}`);
    } else {
     await message.pin({ reason: `Pinned by ${interaction.user.tag}` });
     await interaction.followUp(`Pinned message: ${messageLink}`);
    }
   }
  } catch(error) {
   console.error(error);
   await interaction.followUp('Something went wrong')
  }
 },
});

client.once(Events.ClientReady, readyClient => {
 console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${readyClient.user.tag}`);
});

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
 if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
 const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

 if (!command) {
  console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
  return;
 }

 try {
  await command.execute(interaction);
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
   await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
  } else {
   await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
  }
 }
});

client.login(token);
```

The deployment script I'm using is line for line the script provided in the discord.js guide [here](https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/main/code-samples/creating-your-bot/command-deployment/deploy-commands.js) except that line 37 was changed to `Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),` so it would deploy the command globally.

I'm entirely lost at this point. The only response I get is a message that says

> The application did not respond

and an error in the developer console that says

> [Flux] Dispatching MESSAGE_SEND_FAILED

What can I do to make this /pin command work?

Comment: What version of `discord.js`are you using?

Comment: @Viriato The `discord.js` version listed in my `package.json` file is `14.14.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code:

- You can't use the `followUp` method of an `Interaction` before replying to it, and `deferReply` does not count as one. After deferring an interaction, you must use the `editReply` method on the `interaction` object.
- `interaction.options.get('message').value` is not valid syntax. You're looking for `interaction.options.getString('message', true)`. The second parameter states that this is a required command option.
- There is no `isPinned` property in a `Message` object, you're looking for `pinned`.
- The `pin` and `unpin` methods of a `Message` object accepts a single string parameter that represents the reason of the pinning, not an object with a `reason` property.